# Why does ALSO usage lead to different results in R2 and R3?

Tags: rebol

This code returns `-1` for R3 and `+1` for R2. I'd like to know what I am doing wrong.

```
 f: func [] [
     also  return  1
           return -1
 ]
 f
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong; unfortunately you are tripped up by [a known bug in R3](http://issue.cc/r3/1509). Basically, the `also` incorrectly "eats up" the `return`. Fortunately, we have a fix for this forthcoming. (If you want to help with testing, have a look at my [fix-unwind-passing](https://github.com/earl/r3/tree/fix-unwind-passing) branch.) I hope we'll have this fix done and integrated shortly.

Answer (score 2):

That is already listed as a bug in R3. The correction is on the way, AFAIK.